# how to make sure packages in my python venv are found first (before PYTHONPATH)

Tags: python, pythonpath, python-venv

I'm working with a distributed package system (happens to be [CVMFS](https://cvmfs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) but I don't think the particulars are relevant).  The setup script for that environment adds some locations to PYTHONPATH.

Now, working in that environment, I want to install newer versions of some packages that are already found within that path.  Installing the packages is easy, I can either do

```
python -m pip install --user --upgrade <packages>
```

or, my preferred approach, use a virtual environment

```
python -m venv myenv
source myenv/bin/activate
python -m pip install --upgrade <packages>
```

Installation works fine.  But then when I try to run python, the directories in PYTHONPATH are search before either my user-site directory or the virtual environment, and I get the old versions of packages.

Is there any way to force packages in my virtual environment or user-site path to have priority, without having to manually edit sys.path or PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Why do you have `PYTHONPATH` set, exactly? If your virtualenv must have priority, *don't use `PYTHONPATH` or explicitly list your venv `lib/pythonx.y/site-packages/` directory in your `PYTHONPATH` value.

Comment: It's unfortunate that CVMFS uses `PYTHONPATH` in this regard.

Comment: @MartijnPieters CVMFS is primarily for getting NON-python stuff, such as CERN's ROOT.  But there are also python bindings for ROOT that require ROOT shared libraries, so it makes some sense to distribute those along with all the other libraries.  Does python have any other mechanism other than PYTHONPATH to distribute packages like that?

Comment: The only mention of `PYTHONPATH` I can find anywhere in the cvmfs GitHub organisation is [in the buildout bootstrap.py script](https://github.com/cvmfs/collectd-cvmfs/blob/d280c7e632f39e4af1e91236a4ca27fcbd6aabfb/bootstrap.py#L100-L107), and doesn't appear to be a requirement for *running* cvmfs.

Comment: The current best-practice is to use a dedicated virtualenv for projects like that. PYTHONPATH, when set at the shell level, is not suitable for system-wide installations as it would affect *any of a wide range of Python versions*. E.g. Python 3-only libraries would suddenly be imported into Python 2 code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters forgive my ignorance, but this is somewhat relevant to me for something else I'm working on.  If the centrally-distributed python packages were done via venv rather than `PYTHONPATH`, I could not then work in my own venv and still access it, correct?   In this particular case I want to override a very small subset of the central (CVMFS) modules while still having access to the rest of them as-is.  I didn't think you could have access to more than one venv at a time

Comment: If you need access to the *library* from your *code*, then you need to install it into the Python version you are working with. For *command-line utilities*, it doesn't matter, because the command-line utilities are configured with the right Python executable.